# Spring View Mapping Problem

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've got a problem with my View Mapping in the Spring Web MVC.

Dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
...
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<context:component-scan base-package="de.bigbohne.smartmeter.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
   <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
</bean>
...
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class FrontPage {

    @RequestMapping("/index.htm")
    public ModelAndView Index(Model mdl){
       ModelAndView mav =  new ModelAndView("frontPage.jsp");
       return mav;
    }
}
```

I get an **404 Error** saying that it's missing */SmartMeter/WEB-INF/views/index*

In my oppinion it must be: */SmartMeter/WEB-INF/views/frontPage.jsp*

What am I missing? (I'm using Jetty 7.2 and Spring 3.0.5)

**Edit 1:**

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a suffix to the view resolver:

```
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

Comment: ok, but that's not resolving my problem ... it is still searching von "index.jsp" insted of "frontPage.jsp"

Comment: @Bigbohne what's the url-pattern for DispatcherServlet in web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
```

to

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
```